# What is the content of the unsubscribe message?

Tags: mobile-mail

Introduced in iOS 10, a standard message for unsubscribing can be sent in a couple of taps from any Mail message that was sent to a list.

[image]

Since this feature allows the Mail app to send an email on my behalf and from my e-mail address (I suppose), I would love to know what message the recipient receives.

Comment: http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/

Answer (score 1):

It'll not send an e-mail, it'll just try to find an unsubscribe link and activate it.